# What does it mean when PostgreSQL "truncates" an unlogged table in the case of a crash?

Tags: postgresql

[The PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtable.html) states:

> an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown

What exactly does "truncate" mean in this context? Is it the same as a [`TRUNCATE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-truncate.html)?

I was under the impression that unlogged tables are still persisted, but just not written to the WAL - but the wording makes it sound like data that is already persisted to disk for the that table will be removed or lost in a crash. But I don't see why/how data that is already persisted to disk would be affected.

Comment: [Initialization Fork](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-init.html): *Each unlogged table, and each index on an unlogged table, has an initialization fork. The initialization fork is an empty table or index of the appropriate type. When an unlogged table must be reset to empty due to a crash, the initialization fork is copied over the main fork, and any other forks are erased (they will be recreated automatically as needed).* Since the tables are not logged there is no way to verify the validity of the table data so they are reset in case of unclean shutdown.

Comment: Yes, it means that the table is emptied.

Comment: A possible workaround would be to use a [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) and then run [Refresh Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) on a schedule to fetch that data. You could then transfer that data back to the unlogged table after unclean shutdown/restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a WAL log, there is no way of knowing what the state of the data would be after a crash.  Afterall, that is the point of having WAL.  So the only safe thing to do without WAL is truncate the data, leaving the table defined but empty the same way TRUNCATE does.

It would be nice if there were a way to freeze the table such that it would be read-only and then (once a final checkpoint was run) it would be safe to just leave it alone after a crash, but there is no such mechanism in place.

Comment: Other issues (for us) are the fact that these tables are not replicated and you can't use WAL archiving and point-in-time-recovery.